# One-to-one relationship EF database first

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am having issues regarding one to one relationship in entity framework database first.

I have two tables, a user table and a user details table.

user would consist of login info, username, date registered and the userDetails would have information such as contact information, website, etc.
In my database My user.id references userdetails.userId. Both are primary keys.

So for example..

```
User:
Id [Primary Key (incremented)]
Password
Salt
RegisteredDate

UserDetails
UserId [Primary Key (References User.Id)]
Firstname
Contact
```

My issue is I can add records through SQL Server but EF throws an exception.

How can I successfully create a one to one relationship in EF 6?

Answer (score 0):

Your `UserDetails` should be:

```
UserDetails
UserDetailId [Primary Key (incremented)]
UserId [Foreign Key (References User.Id)]
Firstname
Contact
```

You can create a `UNIQUE INDEX` on your `foreign key`

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_UserId] ON [dbo].[UserDetails]
(
    [UserId] ASC
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: oh, I thought you didn't need a userDetailsId unless your creating a one to many.

Comment: No. You can define a Unique Index on your Foreign Key

Answer (score 0):

Try with a model like this:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //...

    //navigation property
    public UserDetail UserDetail { get; set; }
}

public class UserDetail
{
    [Key,ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    //...

    //navigation property
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

This is using [Data Annotation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx). If you want to use [Fluent Api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx), you could override the `OnModelCreating` method on your Context this way:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Configure UserId as PK for UserDetail
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserDetail>()
        .HasKey(e => e.UserId);

    // Configure StudentId as FK for StudentAddress
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasOptional(u => u.UserDetail) // Mark UserDetail as optional for User
                .WithRequired(ud=> ud.User); // Create inverse relationship

}
```

Remember encrypt the password field.

Comment: Hi, as I am using database first i can't modify the model. Passwords are one way encrypted.

Comment: The problem is I don't know the type of your fields in DB, but this is the proper way to specify an one-to-one relationship in EF, just look the relationship mapping, you have to do that, even in database first. BTW, what is the exception is throwing you?